# H2 console shows tables of all schema for MySQL

Tags: mysql, h2

H2 console can be used to connect to other databases too. For instance, MySQL.

However, when connected to MySQL, it shows tables of all schema and not just the tables of connected schema.

What could be the issue?

Using Version 1.4.199 (http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.199/h2-1.4.199.jar)

MySQL server is running
[image]

Start h2 with `java -jar h2-1.4.199.jar`

Select and open “Generic MySQL” and open “bankdb” schema (JDBC JAR is latest 8.0.16 and located in same folder)

Logging into MySQL with H2
[image]

On left side, shows tables of all schema, including tables of desired schema. (Expected: show tables of only "bankdb")
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behavior with other multi-database tools, such as HeidiSQL.  There is nothing wrong with seeing other schemas per se, so long as you can connect to your desired database from within the tool.  Are the only three tables in the `bankdb` database `account`, `customer`, and `transaction`?  If so, then it means that you did connect to the correct database.  You might also want to poke around and make certain that the `USE <database>` command works properly.

Comment: Yes there are only `account`, `customer`, and `transaction` in `bankdb`. The connection is to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankdb` (see image)

Comment: Nothing is wrong, this is just how the tool works.  Other RDBMS, such as SQL Server and Postgres, also might show other schemas/databases even though you connect via only one database.